# integrating googleplus in android fetch (gender and birthday)

Tags: java, android, google-plus

am trying to fetch gender and birthday from googleplus integration in android ...
    but getting gender as  "0" please help me on this..am attaching my code ..please find the below
    code..birthday is showing as empty..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        }
    });


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
//  mGoogleApiClient.connect();



}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            startIntentSenderForResult(result.getResolution()
                    .getIntentSender(), RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {

            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}



public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {

        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();         

        try {
            int genderInt = currentPerson.getGender();
         String   gender     = String.valueOf(genderInt);
        String birthday = currentPerson.getBirthday();

        System.out.println("gender" + gender + "bod" + birthday);

        } 


        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}



@Override
public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult peopleData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
            PersonBuffer personBuffer = peopleData.getPersonBuffer();
            try {
              int count = personBuffer.getCount();
              for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Display name: " + personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
              }
            } finally {
              personBuffer.close();
            }
          } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error requesting people data: " + peopleData.getStatus());
          }
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

getGender() returns int..
0 - Male, 1 - Female..

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html#getGender()

Comment: It's funny how docs say value is "male" , "female" ... thanks for clarifying :)