# Getting name, gender, location of "me" from GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-signin

In an Android app I have followed the example [Accessing Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client) sofar that the `GoogleApiClient` connection is successful and the `onConnected` callback is called.

However the Google's example stops there and I don't know how to retrieve the **name**, **gender** and **location** of myself (also known as **me** in JavaScript+PHP SDK for Google+ that I had used some time ago).

Here is the Java code (retrying and rotation handling skipped for brevity, it seems to work) why is `me` is null?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) { // why is me null?

    Person me = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

    Person.Name name = me.getName();
    String given = name.getGivenName();
    String family = name.getFamilyName();

    Log.d(TAG, "Given: " + given + ", Family: " + family);
}
```

Please advise how to fetch the data of the logged in user from Google+

**UPDATE:**

What I have tried to solve my problem:

1) I have added `.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)` to the builder call.

2) I have added 2 more permissions to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

In the [Google Developers Console / Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com) I have put both the keys from my real keystore and from .android\debug.keystore:

[image: console]

**I don't understand where/if to use the "Client IDs" show above?**

**And I only have 2 APIs enabled: Google+ and GCM - is maybe more needed?**

[image: api]

3) Finally, I have called

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GooglePlusPlatform VERBOSE
```

and have seen the following error:

```
E/Volley  ( 3890): [594] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
D/GooglePlusPlatform( 3890): Unexpected response code (403) when requesting: getPerson
W/GooglePlusPlatform( 3890): {"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","message":"Access Not Configured. The API (Google+ API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."}],"code":403}
```

I am using a real device (HTC M9) and my app is not published yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by looking at

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GooglePlusPlatform VERBOSE
adb logcat
```

output and enabling the **Google Play Android Developer API** in [Google Developers Console / Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/) (the API was missing before):

[image: console]

And here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Person me = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (me != null) {
        Person.Name name = me.getName();
        String given = name.getGivenName();
        String family = name.getFamilyName();
        boolean female = (me.hasGender() && me.getGender() == 1);

        String photo = null;
        if (me.hasImage() && me.getImage().hasUrl()) {
            photo = me.getImage().getUrl();
        }

        String city = "Unknown city";
        List<Person.PlacesLived> places = me.getPlacesLived();
        if (places != null) {
            for (Person.PlacesLived place : places) {
                city = place.getValue();
                if (place.isPrimary())
                    break;
            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Given: " + given + 
                 ", Family: " + family + 
                 ", Female: " + female + 
                 ", City: " + city);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this way? If it helps

```
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

  Person me = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

  if (me != null) {

    String personName = me.getDisplayName();         

    try {
        int genderInt = me.getGender();//0 for male, and 1 for female 
        String   gender     = String.valueOf(genderInt);
        String birthday = me.getBirthday();

        System.out.println("gender" + gender + "bod" + birthday);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
  }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)` returns `null`

Comment: look at this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908362/integrating-googleplus-in-android-fetch-gender-and-birthday

Comment: I guess it will solve your problem for sure. May be user is not logged in. That is why it returns null. If my answer helped you please accept my answer. Thanks and best of luck